# clear a textbox after checking a radiobutton and type like windows calculator in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, radio-button

I'm making a decimal to binary, hexadecimal, octal and reversal calculator. I'm trying to imitate the Windows Calculator, where with radio buttons you can switch among the different conversions. This is how it works: 1- type your number, 2- select the desired base to convert to, 3- when you type another number, the calculator textbox gets erased so you start with a brand new number (so you don't have to press any clear button).

Is there a way to accomplish this?
I would really appreciate your help!, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
Maybe this method you will find useful

Answer (score 0):

I have made a short example for you here. The text will be deleted automatically after clicking.

**Example**

```
if(radiobutton1.checked){

textbox.text = "";

}
```